# Why wouldn't this doesn't execute the second printf?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, posix

So this mate of mine comes asking for help with some fork/pipe stuff, and his code didn't work.
Starting off I just attributed to it being a mess, but then I got to reading some more, I started stripping away all the stuff that might have been wrong, ended up with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>

typedef void (*tFunction)();

pid_t CreateProcess(tFunction toExecute){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid)return pid;
    else  {toExecute();exit(0);}
}

void Producer_1(){
    printf("IM PROCESS 1\n");
    printf("Why I no print");
    while(1){}
}
int main(){
    CreateProcess(Producer_1);
    wait(0);
}
```

With as the output:
[image]
It ofc holds after, but what's up with printf here?
If you place a newline in the end of the last string, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Writes to `stdout` are line buffered by default.  That means that text written to `stdout` won't be flushed until a newline character is written.

If you don't write a newline, the text sits in the buffer.

Comment: Yep, add `fflush(stdout)` to have the text printed.

Comment: Or better yet add the newline to the second print statement `printf("Why I no print\n");`

Comment: @eckenrod how is your solution working. As far as I knew, `\n` does nothing but print a newline and the problem exists because the program is not clearing the buffer. So, how come your solution is working? Am I missing something?

Comment: @scipsycho Printing a newline to a line buffered stream implicitly flushes the buffer.